# Add a static value in list when using Except

Tags: c#, linq, except

I am using two lists

```
List<int> a = {1,2,3};
List<int> b = {3};
```

and using Except to compare and filter them.

```
var diff = a.Except(b).ToList();
```

this returns values as

```
1
2
```

I need to return a bool value along with that ie. the return values should be as

```
1 true
2 true
```

the return type is a `List<modelClass>` that has `int id, bool isTrue` properties

Can you help me in doing this ?

Comment: And what defines that boolean value? How do you know if its true or false?

Comment: That will be only `true`

Comment: If a Boolean value is ever going to be true, why do you need it in first place?

Comment: I'm sorry bro the question actually fulfills part of my requirement. the actual question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251091/compare-two-lists-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
var diff = a.Except(b)
            .Select(s=>new modelClass(){id = s, isTrue = true})
            .ToList();
```