# Compare two lists C#

Tags: c#, linq, compare

I am having two lists

```
List<int> a = {1,2,3};
List<int> b = {3,4};
```

I need to compare them in such a way that the output should be

```
1 false
2 false
4 true
```

The output is by using the following logic

- `1,2` are in `a` but not in `b` so they are set to `false` whereas
- `3` is in both the lists so its not in the output and
- '4' is in `b` but not in `a` so they are set to `true`

the return type is a `List<modelClass>` that has `int id, bool isTrue` properties

Can you help me?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you chose to provide example output but not an explanation of the rules that would produce such output?  If you can't do this with pen and paper then how can you write code to do it?  If you can do it with pen and paper then you know the steps required and you can tell us.

Comment: tel us the business.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26250875/1324033)? What makes 1 and 2 false but 4 true? Given the current explanation `x - 4 == 0` would be enough to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: You are supposed to show some effort. If you need a coder to do your work, go pay one.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? You iterate over the first list and compare it with every item of the second list and then over the second list and compare it with every item of the first list. That's the manual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about performance you can use the following LINQ:

```
a.Except(b)
  .Union(b.Except(a))
  .Select(item => new { id = item, isTrue = b.Contains(item) });
```

With `HashSet` usage:

```
var setA = new HashSet<int>(a);
var setB = new HashSet<int>(b);
setA.SymmetricExceptWith(b);

var result = setA.Select(item => new { id = item, isTrue = setB.Contains(item) });
```